# Can I add a object to TreeMap without reference

Tags: java, object, treemap, concurrenthashmap

I have basic Rectangle class. Can I use the object without reference? I'tried but it seems like only adding the last one.

```
public class Rectangle implements Comparable {

int a1;
int a2;

public Rectangle (int a1, int a2) {
    this.a1= a1;
    this.a2= a2;
}

    TreeMap<Rectangle, String > rectangleStringTreeMap = new TreeMap<>();
    rectangleStringTreeMap.put(new Rectangle(2,5),"This is first");
    rectangleStringTreeMap.put(new Rectangle(3,7),"This is second");
    rectangleStringTreeMap.put(new Rectangle(4,8),"This is third");
```

Comment: Share your implementation of the `compareTo` method in `Rectangle`.  That is likely to be the cause of your problems.   Ummm ... and why does your question title say `HashMap` when the code is using a `TreeMap`?

Comment: And you'd be getting warnings about raw types for `Comparable` (instead of `Comparable<Rectangle>`).

Comment: Even if you appear to have answered your own question, you should still post the missing code for `equals()` and `compareTo`. Otherwise, others will not be able to understand what the problem was and why your answer solved it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your class is primarily meant to be a transparent immutable carrier of data, define your class as a [record](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/395). In a record, the compiler implicitly creates the constructor, getters, `equals` & `hashCode`, and `toString` by considering each and every member field.

Make your class implement `Comparable` using generics rather than as a raw type.

Define a `Comparator` with two clauses, to do the comparing work.

Something like this untested code.

```java
public record Rectangle ( int a1 , int a2 ) implements Comparable < Rectangle >
{
    static private Comparator < Rectangle > comparator = 
            Comparator
                .comparingInt( Rectangle :: a1 )
                .thenComparingInt( Rectangle :: a2 ) ;
    
    @Override
    public int compareTo( Rectangle other )
    {
        return Rectangle.comparator.compare( this , other ) ;
    }
}
```

Proceed with your map. But declare your map as the more general interface `NavigableMap` rather than the concrete class `TreeMap`.

```
NavigableMap < Rectangle, String > rectangleStringNavMap = new TreeMap<>();
rectangleStringNavMap.put( new Rectangle(2,5), "This is first" );
rectangleStringNavMap.put( new Rectangle(3,7), "This is second" );
rectangleStringNavMap.put( new Rectangle(4,8), "This is third" );
```

If working with the map across threads, use `ConcurrentNavigableMap` interface, and `ConcurrentSkipListMap` class.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem while using comparator instead of using Comparable interface.

```
public class Rectangle{

int a1;
int a2;

public Rectangle (int a1, int a2) {
    this.a1= a1;
    this.a2= a2;
}

     TreeMap<Rectangle, String > rectangleStringTreeMap = new TreeMap<>(new Comparator<Rectangle>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Rectangle o1, Rectangle o2) {
            if (o1.a1 > o2.a1 && o1.a2 > o2.a2) {
                return 1;
            } else if (o1.a1 < o2.a1 && o1.a2 < o2.a2) {
                return -1;
            } else return 0;
        }
    });
    rectangleStringTreeMap.put(new Rectangle(2,5),"This is first");
    rectangleStringTreeMap.put(new Rectangle(3,7),"This is second");
    rectangleStringTreeMap.put(new Rectangle(4,8),"This is third");
```

Comment: Basil Bourque's [comparator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70181554/15472) is much better, in that it only returns 0 for truly equal attributes (it is also more idiomatic and easier to read). Your comparator would also return 0 for (1,0) vs (0, 1) -- which you likely do not want to consider as equals.